# Bootstrap 3 table : different views in iPhone and Web

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering what is the best way to implement a table with 4-5 columns (see bootply link) in web layout to be displayed in a one column layout on the mobile as shown in the attached image.

http://www.bootply.com/lbwyJCglxA#

[image]

Comment: Could you post a smaller mockup, just to not take a lot of the page?

Comment: Also, just to clarify, you have a table on the desktop. Each row has columns, going from left-to-right. Instead, on mobile, you want a row in which columns go up-to-down? I think I know what you need, but just need this info

Comment: yes, this is what I need

Comment: Okay. I see that someone gave an answer. I will provide another solution tonight. Sorry for the wait!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into this [Responsive Tables](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/#)

Original Snippet Source: [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  #no-more-tables table,
  #no-more-tables thead,
  #no-more-tables tbody,
  #no-more-tables th,
  #no-more-tables td,
  #no-more-tables tr {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  #no-more-tables thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  #no-more-tables tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  #no-more-tables td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #no-more-tables td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  /*
 Label the data
 */
  #no-more-tables td:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">
                No more tables.
            </h1>

      <h3 class="text-center">
                Resize the browser screen to see how the table changes
            </h3>

    </div>
    <div id="no-more-tables">
      <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
        <thead class="cf">
          <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th class="numeric">Price</th>
            <th class="numeric">Change</th>
            <th class="numeric">Change %</th>
            <th class="numeric">Open</th>
            <th class="numeric">High</th>
            <th class="numeric">Low</th>
            <th class="numeric">Volume</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
            <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AAD</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ARDENT LEISURE GROUP</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">1.32%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.14</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.13</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">56,431</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AAX</td>
            <td data-title="Company">AUSENCO LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$4.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.04</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.99%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$4.01</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$4.05</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$4.00</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">90,641</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ABC</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ADELAIDE BRIGHTON LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.06</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">2.04%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$2.98</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.00</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$2.96</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">862,518</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ABP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ABACUS PROPERTY GROUP</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.91</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">0.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.00%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.92</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.93</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.90</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">595,701</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ABY</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ADITYA BIRLA MINERALS LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$0.77</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">2.00%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$0.76</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$0.77</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$0.76</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">54,567</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ACR</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ACRUX LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.71</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.01</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.14%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$3.70</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.72</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$3.68</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">191,373</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ADU</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ADAMUS RESOURCES LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$0.72</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">0.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.00%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$0.73</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$0.74</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$0.72</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">8,602,291</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AGG</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ANGLOGOLD ASHANTI LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$7.81</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.22</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-2.74%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$7.82</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$7.82</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$7.81</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">148</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AGK</td>
            <td data-title="Company">AGL ENERGY LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$13.82</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.14%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$13.83</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$13.83</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$13.67</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">846,403</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AGO</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ATLAS IRON LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.17</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.47%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$3.11</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.22</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$3.10</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">5,416,303</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="bg-success" style="padding:10px;margin-top:20px"><small><a href="http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/#no-more-tables" target="_blank">Link</a> to original article</small>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```